# Permission Denied Error on writing to XLS file using xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am using xlwt package in python to create a workbook, write tabular data in the cells of an excel sheet. Finally, I save the workbook as an existing file name (let's say List_Of_Animals.xls).

If the file is already open on someone's computer (which is a possibility as our customers may often to forget to close the Excel sheet they're viewing), the python script fails saying permissions to write is missing.

Isn't there a way to overwrite the file even if it is open somewhere by removing the lock? Can we do this using xlwt?

Note: The code runs on Windows computer and customers use windows computer mostly. (gave this information just if it is required)

Comment: I think the answer is a "NO". The protecting of open files this way is an OS level feature, which I don't think Python can work around. You might just have to save to a temporary filename, and then try periodically overwriting the file